# Can't run app on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working in a game (SpriteKit-Swift). Until yesterday was running fine on my device, but today I opened Xcode and a bunch of compiler errors appeared on my code, even on the automatic code that Xcode builts for you were errors. I managed to fix all errors by creating a new program and coping the new automatic codes to my program, I assume Apple Changed some libraries. My app runs perfectly in the iOS simulators (5,5s,6,6+) but when I run the app on my iPhone the app crashes and Xcode shows me this in the editor (not console).

```
 dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
 0x120099088:  brk    #3 //MESSAGE POINTS HERE
```

With a message to the 2nd line "Threat 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subdued=0x120099088)

also shows this on another file:

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
0x120099000:  mov    x28, sp
0x120099004:  and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x120099008:  movz   x0, #0
0x12009900c:  movz   x1, #0
0x120099010:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-16]!
0x120099014:  mov    fp, sp
0x120099018:  sub    sp, sp, #16
0x12009901c:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x120099020:  ldr    x1, [x28, #8]
0x120099024:  add    x2, x28, #16
0x120099028:  adrp   x4, -1
0x12009902c:  mov    x4, x4
0x120099030:  adrp   x3, 40
0x120099034:  ldr    x3, [x3, #880]
0x120099038:  sub    x3, x4, x3
0x12009903c:  mov    x5, sp
0x120099040:  bl     0x12009908c               ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
0x120099044:  mov    x16, x0 //MESSAGE POINTS HERE
0x120099048:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x12009904c:  cmp    x1, #0
0x120099050:  b.ne   0x12009905c               ; _dyld_start + 92
0x120099054:  add    sp, x28, #8
0x120099058:  br     x16
0x12009905c:  mov    lr, x1
0x120099060:  ldr    x0, [x28, #8]
0x120099064:  add    x1, x28, #16
0x120099068:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x12009906c:  add    x2, x2, #8
0x120099070:  mov    x3, x2
0x120099074:  ldr    x4, [x3]
0x120099078:  add    x3, x3, #8
0x12009907c:  cmp    x4, #0
0x120099080:  b.ne   0x120099074               ; _dyld_start + 116
0x120099084:  br     x16
```

With the same message  "Threat 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subdued=0x120099088)

Comment: It looks like your program hit a breakpoint that you set up.

Comment: I didn't there are no break points, shouldn't the breakpoints hit also if I run the program on the iOS Simulators? but in the simulator program runs perfectly fine. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Try clean and build, toggle some break points, update Xcode, erase Derived Data, delete and reinstall app, etc. If you don't have any breakpoints, Xcode thinks you do. Also, you should be able to type `c` at the `(lldb)` prompt to continue execution.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I can now run the App on my iPhone. You should post that as the solution. Appreciate.

Comment: Unfortunately only "toggle the global breakpoint state" helped me. Xcode must think that there is a breakpoint somewhere, thx aaron for the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a clean build using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wahoo Great I've first tried to find out my project targets, and then to change UiKit, I did the following:
To weak-link a framework, find your application target in Xcode, inspect it, and go to the General tab. At the bottom of that tab should be a list of frameworks, with a column for Type. Change the Type for UIKit from Required to Weak and rebuild your application. That should take care of the runtime errors.
But this has not helped me anywhere.
So I did cleaning by finally **( Command + Option + Shift + K )** this has worked for me.